# Which dependency to install?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven

I am getting the `FileNotFoundException` for not being able to find `org/springframework/session/data/mongo/config/annotation/web/reactive/ReactiveMongoWebSessionConfiguration.class`

I tried adding `spring-session` and `spring-sesson-data-mongo` dependencies, but still it doesn't solve the problem. So what dependency should i use?

Here is full stack trace if it is needed -

```
2018-07-31 14:45:16 WARN  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/mongo/config/annotation/web/reactive/ReactiveMongoWebSessionConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2018-07-31 14:45:16 INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-31 14:45:16 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/mongo/config/annotation/web/reactive/ReactiveMongoWebSessionConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at Application.main(Application.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/mongo/config/annotation/web/reactive/ReactiveMongoWebSessionConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:734)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:950)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Here is my `pom.xml` -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.airtel</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootHibernate</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-mongo</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is this exception on runtime?

Comment: What version oh Spring and `spring-sesson-data-mongo` do you use? Pls paste your `pom.xml`. If you use Spring Boot 2.0.x you may try `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive`

Comment: @MarioSantini yes it was on runtime

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev i have added `pom.xml`

Comment: adding `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive` dependency didnt help solve the exception

Comment: @monster it looks like a version conflict on your classpath. Try to use [spring-session-data-mongodb](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session-data-mongodb) instead of `spring-sesson-data-mongo`. I can also recommend you to use the `spring-boot-dependencies` import instead of `spring-framework-bom` is you use Spring Boot. Then you'll be able to remove explicit version for most of the Spring artefacts.